# Cannot find declaration to go to - Atualização Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Olá, eu atualizei o flutter recentemente, e agora o projeto não quer rodar... Creio que seja algo da nova atualização...

O erro é esse aí abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Segundo o [changelog do pacote](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker/changelog) há uma breaking change na 2.0.0 -> "NumberPicker.integer is now NumberPicker."

Comment: show!!! muito obrigada!!! acho que consegui resolver aqui...

Comment: mas quando vou executar, dá nisso... (isso tava dando ruim já no início...

Comment: /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_duration_picker-1.0.4/lib/flutter_duration_picker.dart:506:44: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
    final Widget actions = new ButtonTheme.bar(
                                           ^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Parece problema com outro widget (ButtonTheme), vê se isso aqui resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66027441/4056678 - parece que tem que mudar `ButtonTheme.bar` para `ButtonBarTheme`. Talvez seja bom travar as versões das dependências no seu pubspec.yml para não ter surpresas com updates.